# MySQL vs Sqlite: which is better for in-memory DB?

Tags: mysql, sqlite, in-memory-database

If some records are needed to be stored in memory, which is the better choice: MySQL memory engine or Sqlite? Which DB engine has better performance for select operations? Which DB engine occupies less memory?

There are lots of integer comparisons for some columns but not other complicated operations.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3630/sqlite-vs-mysql

Answer (score -3):

It makes sense for SQLite to be faster, hense the 'lite' name.

http://www.sqlite.org/speed.html

Comment: This document is a little old.

Comment: it is not "lite". The correct name is "SQL-ite", as in meteror-ite. The creator has explained this several times.